# How to add avoidance and chase behavior in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to implement the type of behavior where a group of prey is evading from a predator like this [Game](http://collective-behavior.com/apps/fishindanger/webgl/)

I tried to write the script this way but I don't get the desired motion the prey just moves forward.

```
public Transform target;

    public float damping;
    public float drivespeed;

    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * -drivespeed);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion
            .LookRotation(target.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion
            .Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want

```
transform.Translate(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * -drivespeed);
```

instead of

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * -drivespeed);
```

(`Vector3.forward` being a world forward vector, not the object's forward vector.)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the transform.translate is being called before the rotation logic but it's hard to tell what's going wrong here.

- Is the object rotating correctly?
- If so is the transform moving forward ignoring the rotation?
- Are drivespeed and damping variables != 0?